# How to build pst-barcode with xelatex?

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-barcode

In the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3in,0.49in)
    \psbarcode{9781860742712}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.49 width=1.3}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

I have this issue

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.6 ...8 includetext height=0.49 width=1.3}{ean13}
                                                  %
? X
No pages of output.
```

I build my project with:

```
latexmk -xelatex -pdf foo.tex
```

What is this error and how to solve it?

Comment: You should remove `-pdf`, that overwrites the `-xelatex` option and reverts to `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile the following

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.3in,0.49in)
    \psbarcode{9781860742712}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.49 width=1.3}{ean13}%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

with either

- `xelatex something.tex` alone or
- `latex something.tex` followed by `dvips something.dvi` followed by `ps2pdf something.ps`

to get the following result

[image]

Note that: the second option usually runs much much faster than the first option.